# QML drop down menu crash

Tags: qt, notifications, segmentation-fault, symbian, qml

When I pull down the notification menu in my QML (Qt Quick) app with the standard implementation off it I get this error: "Thread has crashed: A data abort exception has occurred accessing 0x20". This also happens if I just create a new Symbian Qt Quick app and just run it without any modification. Do you have any idea what might be causing it?

While using the debugger it says: sigsegv segmentation fault.

Comment: Any code ? Any reference to class names ?

Comment: i have identical behaviour on my app ... then i realize the same bug happens for other apps as for example Nokia Store ... so that is a Nokia bug .. don't know any workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also happened to me several months back and I was able to find a solution.
Some Nokia beta applications bundle QT Quick Components in their installation sis. This conflicts with the built in installation and causes this issue.

The solution is to install another copy of QT Quick Components and then uninstalling it from the Application Manager. You can it from the Nokia QT SDK installer, or you can google for QtQuickComponents-1.1-for-Anna-Belle.sis

Comment: I ended up having to reinstall Belle but I will use this next time.